# Unknown object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel to index objects into MongoDb. Now this is working fine but the problem is that when I query my MongoDb with `db.published.find().pretty()` I find some unexpected objects that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51a8822231da90cab7d75553"),
    "error" : null,
    "lazy" : true,
    "lastError" : {
        "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017",
        "n" : 0,
        "lastOp" : NumberLong("5884095995700051970"),
        "connectionId" : 6,
        "err" : null,
        "ok" : 1
    },
    "n" : 0,
    "cachedLastError" : {
        "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017",
        "n" : 0,
        "lastOp" : NumberLong("5884095995700051970"),
        "connectionId" : 6,
        "err" : null,
        "ok" : 1
    },
    "lastConcern" : null
}
```

What are these objects? Should they be in my collection and if so why?

Comment: Is there a logging/error logging system? (MongoDB doesn't add documents to your collections like that - so it must be some other software component).

Comment: Ahh, could be. I'll check. But you're absolutely sure that its not the db itself?

Comment: I agree with @WiredPrairie, it is definitely not MongoDB inserting these documents.

Comment: Probably the camel component then: http://camel.apache.org/mongodb.html

Comment: Most likely, yes, it's the camel mongodb component (or a related error logging system that uses the DB configuration in some way).